# convert macro plot to gwt

Tags: java, excel, gwt, vba

I have an excel Macro that takes log information and creats a plot out of this information.

I was wondering if there is a way that I can convert this macro into GWT.  Or is this evan possible?

I know this isn't alot to go off of, but I am just trying to get ideas to see if this can be done.  If it cannot be done in GWT what about regular java?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Transfer your data into Google Docs spreadsheet. Than use it to plot a chart. Then you could use Google API to call the chart onto your browser. Once you are satisfied, you would write a div wrapper around the call to embed the manually created chart into a GWT panel.

I cannot recall immediately how to write a GWT wrapper around a Google API (or a jquery generated) chart. You could google/search Blessed Geek Google Map GWT wrapper.

That brings to question,
After that, you could write a routine to programmatically insert data into the spreadsheet.

But a second question is - could you programmatically trigger a plot on google spreadsheet? The last time I had dealt with google spreadsheet programmatically was two years ago. A lot must have changed. Otherwise, you should have to withdraw data as plot points from google docs API and feed it into Google Chart API.

As I believe, Google APIs are moving away from supplying GWT libraries, but towards supplying just the javascript library -- for the simple fact is you could simply write GWT wrappers around them and that is what is being done by javascript charting library suppliers.

OTOH, you could use one of the javascript charting libraries: HighCharts, ZingChart, etc.

Comment: BTW, I learnt how to write GWT wrappers around javascript/jquery generated visual output by reading into the code of http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-highcharts/.

Comment: I should have put this in my question, but this will be on a server that won't have access to an outside internet connection.  so anything the is server side isn't the best idea.  I was already using GCharts in my other app and was wondering if there may be a way to place the plots into a chart and have them displayed that way.

Comment: quantrix.com but it costs a lot of money - used by the big boys.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can probably do this in GWT.